# Setting visibility of menu / block

Tags: blocks, navigation

I am trying to set the visibility OF A a menu block, so that only certain roles can see it. This seems like a simple task,  but I am having trouble getting it to work. I have using Drupal 7 btw.

To create a menu I go into Structure>>Menus>>Add Menu, and add a link,

This then, tells me that it created a block in the block administration page, which it did. When I selected a Role, which I know I am definetly not in, I am still able to see the Menu(and I should not be able to see it since I am not in that role). Similarly, I am not able to see some new menus that I create at all, even if I don't have any restriction on the roles.

I am not sure why this is why happening, and don't really understand it. Some insight will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:  I should also mention that I recently moved my site to a new server. After moving the site, some things went kind of wancky. I don't know if this is related, but my previous site had the In Place Panel Editor in the front page. Now that is gone. I could have controlled the visibility from that(THE PANELS) as well, but it is very difficult to change the settings the settings UI interface is all messed up.

Comment: are you logged in as user with administrator role? if so, you'll have access to all the menu's despite the role restriction.

Comment: Thanks pown. I am signed with an administrator role. But I am still not seeing all the menus I created. Furthermore, when sign is as a different user (with no administrative role) I still see the same menus.

Comment: did you go into that menu's links list and see how they are structured? it should give you a "tree" heirarchy and there you should see where your links are located. If a parent is hidden then its children will be hidden too. Also, the [Menu Item Visibility module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) can help here possibly.